# Is there an elegant way to share & enforce rest api signature with client app (angular/mobile)?

Tags: rest, single-page-application

In a classic setup of SPA/mobile app consuming REST service, is there a way to ensure that client app is always using current API contract?

Ideally, client app wouldnt build in case it doesnt use request/response parameters/types.

Something like, API shares its contract and client app (being typesafe) loads it dynamically.

If its needed, monorepo can be used to hold the both code bases.

Answer (score 1):

I think REST is not what you think it is. It seems you treat it as RPC thing where you have a service API that you call methods/endpoints on and get some API specific response back that your client is tailored for. This, unfortunately, is not what REST is or should be.

REST is basically just a generalization of the interaction concepts that are used on the Web for decades successfully. Its main purpose here is to decouple clients from servers to allow the latter one to evolve freely over time, introduce changes clients will adapt naturally to as these are designed with constant change in mind. Your browser is a perfect example for such a client. It does not need to get updated when you want to interact with page X or Y regardless if they are provided by various services.

REST is based on 3 interfaces if you will:

- an underlying transport protocol, usually HTTP/S
- a global naming scheme which can be used to reference stuff, which is usually covered by URL/URI/IRI
- and various document type definitions that define the "languages" that services in such an environment understand and speak

So, basically REST just consists of 3 interfaces that both clients and servers need to support in order to interact with each other. REST is designed for distributed interactions and as counter-part to traditional RPC-approaches. The main premise in a REST environment should always be to let servers "teach" clients what they can do next. As such, the whole workflow can usually be designed as some kind of state machine where the service guides a client through a particular task. In the Web world this is usually achieved through Web forms where the server tells your browser basically what properties a certain resource supports and allows you to add/update, where to send the message to, which HTTP operation to use  as well as the media-type to send the payload in, which is usually implicitly given as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

While traditional RPC solutions usually have one syntax they can exchange messages in, i.e. XML for SOAP or Java-specific intermediary object data for RMI and so forth, REST decouples clients and services here and allows to to act on various exchange formats. Instead of setting the contract on the API itself, which is rather common for RPC solutions, REST uses media-type to represent the contract, the language if you will, both client and servers need to "speak" in order for them to be able to interact with each other. So, instead of one contract, REST could potentially support an infinite amount of contracts in various forms.

A media-type is nothing more than a (human-readable) description of what kind of messages can be exchanged, the syntax and elements that are used within a message payload as well as a description of the semantics of each of the elements and in which context they might occur. Think here i.e. of HTML where it defines that `li` (list items) can appear as part of unordered lists (`ul`) or ordered lists (`ol`) and so forth. Both client and service need to be able to "map" their state to a representation format the other understands. HTTP as transport layer here i.e. supports the communication by allowing both of them to negotiate about the content. [REST per se does not have this concept of a resource representing a particular type](https://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). So a resource that contains some user information is not automatically a user object. If so this needs to be mapped from the media type specific response format to an object that can be used by your application. After all, the same data could be expressed probably in `application/vcard-json` or `application/xhtml+xml` or other more or less common [media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

While this may sound tedious and complicating things, this allows participants in a REST environment to really evolve as clients and services aren't coupled. They only act upon the capabilities of the exchange format a.k.a. media-type. Think of a media-type that represents EDI messages like orders, order acknowlegments, invoices and so forth. You could define a new media-type therefore and define the syntax used as well as what elements belong to an invoice, which to an order and so forth. As long as both clients and servers stick to that definition they will be able to exchange messages. The media-type therefore became some form of contract both client and service have to adhere to. On designing own/custom media-types you of course need to pay attention what you want to add and support and how you want to coop with "new" stuff added over time. Either your media-type is released in new versions over time or your media type supports some form of extension mechanism, i.e. through the usage of profiles. Careful design i.e. with backwards compatibility is of upmost importance here. Just look at the HTML specification here which has multiple versions like HTML 4.1 or HTML 5 and so forth. But all of them support older syntax from previous versions as well. Of course, implementing a new media-type dedicated for EDI messages might be a bit wasteful when there are already common media types available like `application/EDIFACT` or `application/EDI-X12` that are widely used and supported by plenty of clients and services.

So, long story short, if you want to "ensure" that your clients act upon the most up-to-date "API version", decouple clients from your service and let them only act upon the media-type contract. As long as the stuff you want to exchanged is covered and supported by the backing media-type definition clients will be able to pick up the change naturally and map those to objects they can further act upon. If something is not yet covered in the used media-type you either need to create a new one, use a more common one that then can be used to map the payload to a language specific object or check whether profiles can be used to add some form of extension capability.

Comment: thank you so much for putting time and effort into this high quality answer. I have to read it a few more times and do my homework but seema like you have pointed me to right direction with `media-type`. will get back soon.